# How to resolve file name issue with multiple interfaces names, created in a file

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

how to :

when i create multiple interface(s) to check details, I have learn that of  multiple extension of interface with interfaces.

it gives me error with file name , because previous I was named the file with interface name ,primarily developed but when i make new interface(s) ,editor  frequently told me to rename the file name with currently developed interface .
what is the conflict & how to resolve .

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also, it helps us a lot when we are provided with code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Each public type has to be in its own file. For example, if you have class declared like this:

```
public class MyClass {...}
```

You have to put it in a file called `MyClass.java`.

An interface is also considered a type in Java. Therefore, if you have an interface such as:

```
public interface MyInterface {....}
```

You also have to put it in its own file named like the name of the interface, that is, `MyInterface.java`.

The same is also true of `enum`. If it's `public enum`, it goes in its own file named like the enum.

If you have non-public types, you can put them in the same file as another type. But as soon as you make them public, you need to move them to their own file.